# Handshake error while calling soap service from code deployed as war in weblogic 11g

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, weblogic, tls1.2

My soap service supports TLSv1.2 only, and when I am calling the soap service from local machine by writing a client in main() method, It works fine. Also I have enabled ssl debugging, So in local I am clearly able to see that I am client is sending
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2.

Issue is when I am deploying my code as a war file in weblogic 10.3.6, with ssl debugging enables, In logs I am getting 
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.
for the same client code in java.

If client is TLSv1, would it not handshake with service TLS1.2 ?

In weblogic console, I have enabled the JSSE. I am clueless about any other configuration that need to be done in weblogic or what could be the possible reason for the handshake error.
Any kind of suggestion is appreciated, Kindly help.

I am pasting my logs below for better clarification:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.readResponseCodeAndMessage(HttpClientTransport.java:218)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:204)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:272)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:153)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:136)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy791.executeProcess(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:84)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy792.executeProcess(Unknown Source)
        at aero.sita.trillium.mobility.util.ServiceHelper.swapAsset(ServiceHelper.java:4309)
        at aero.sita.trillium.mobility.service.impl.IMgmtServiceImpl.swapAssetAsJSON(IMgmtServiceImpl.java:3223)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:71)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.jdbc.aop.DynamicDataSourceTransactionInterceptor.invoke(DynamicDataSourceTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMethodAdvice.java:57)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLAdvice.invoke(PACLAdvice.java:51)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:118)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy691.swapAssetAsJSON(Unknown Source)
        at aero.sita.trillium.mobility.service.IMgmtServiceUtil.swapAssetAsJSON(IMgmtServiceUtil.java:698)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1607)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1776)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1068)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:890)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:764)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$4.run(JaSSLEngine.java:118)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:732)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.unwrap(JaSSLEngine.java:116)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:93)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:59)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.write(JSSEFilterImpl.java:391)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket$JSSEOutputStream.write(JSSESocket.java:78)
```

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

> If client is TLSv1, would it not handshake with service TLS1.2 ?

TLSv1 refers to TLS 1.0 in this case.

> My soap service supports TLSv1.2 only ... deploying my code as a war file in weblogic 10.3.6

TLS 1.2 is probably not supported by your Weblogic installation. According to [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13852/toc.htm#NOTES183) it is supported since Weblogic 11 and when Java 7 or better is used.